# Digitos binarios en plantilla blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy rescatando información de una base de datos y desplegando en una plantilla blade en laravel, el problema que tengo es que me aparecen dígitos binarios sin que yo los haya colocado.la verdad no se que pueda estar pasando.esta es mi plantilla blade:

```
@extends('plantillas.mireporte')
@section('cabecerareporte')
@endsection

@section('cuerporeporte')
  <p class="display h6 text-uppercase text-center">{{$titulo}} </p>
    <div class="container-fluid mx-4">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
              <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="table-active ">  
                    @foreach($lista as $e)
                      <td class="text-uppercase text-white bg-danger">{{ $e }}</td>
                    @endforeach
                  </tr> 

                  @foreach($DATOS as $item)

                  @if($bandera==0)
                    <tr class="table-active ">

                  @foreach($lista as $list)
                      <td>{{$item->$list}}</td>
                  @endforeach
                  {{$bandera=1}}
                    </tr>
                  @else
                    <tr class="bg-white text-dark">

                  @foreach($lista as $list)
                      <td>{{$item->$list}}</td>
                  @endforeach
                  {{$bandera=0}}
                    </tr>
                  @endif

                  @endforeach 
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>
@endsection
```

Esto es lo que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la verdad no se que podra ser, eh revisado las etiquetas y estan bien cerradas todas.

Esto da en el inspector de codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias agregar la imagen del inspector de codigo para ver en que parte especificacmente se pintan, saemos que despues del titulo pero ni mas info!

Comment: ahora lo agrego...

Comment: mira ver pk los numeros binarios esos se estan creando en esta linea <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
              <table class="table">, no tienes ningun javascript que este modificando el dom???

Comment: la verdad no tengo nada de código Javascript

Comment: ¿Cuál es el fin de esa variable $bandera? Parece ser una lógica innecesaria y además en el lugar incorrecto.

Comment: el fin de esa variable es intercalar los colores de las filas en la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh dado con la respuesta
aquí la solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840456/binary-bits-in-my-blade-template-laravel/55840628?noredirect=1#comment98344789_55840628

Tenia que cambiar :

```
{{$bandera=1}}
{{$bandera=0}}
```

Por:

```
@php $bandera=1; @endphp
@php $bandera=0; @endphp
```

Según la documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade

Comment: Esta respuesta no sigue las buenas prácticas de Laravel. -1

Comment: por que marcas negativo? la respuesta ha sido respondida, cosa diferente es "las buenas practicas".

Comment: Al parecer no entiendes cómo funciona Laravel ni Blade, ni cómo aprovechar sus funcionalidades.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una mejor forma de hacer esto de alternar colores, utilizando las herramientas de Blade, más especificamente las propiedades del loop y así evitar escribir tanto código innecesario:

```
<tr class="@if($loop->even) table-active @else bg-white text-dark @endif">

  @foreach($lista as $list)
      <td>{{$item->$list}}</td>
  @endforeach

</tr>
```

Lo que hace este código, más puntualmente el if, es verificar si es un número par dicha iteración, o sea si es el 0, 2, 4 ... y si es así, usar cierta clase, de lo contrario, utilizar otra.

Revisa bien la documentación, Laravel y Blade son muy potentes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops